# How can I easily 'assume-unchanged' subdirectores in git?

Tags: git, gitignore

First let me say that the `.gitignore` feature is not what I'm asking about.  I have some particular directories that must be munged before cross-platform building.  These are library things that will not change for me on a day-to-day basis.  [I learned](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) that the way to do this is

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged
```

which indeed is fine, except that it doesn't understand wildcards or interpret a directory name to include everything under it. (well, half-fine; see below)

It would be handiest if I could just give it the top of the tree that contains library stuff that won't change for me, one name.  But, that doesn't work.

It also isn't really the feature for doing that. It prevents spam in the Unstaged Changes, but it also doesn't stop git from putting everything back the way *it* wants it, from time to time.

Is there some way to do that, or a better way to accomplish what I'm wanting?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure to fully understand what you want, but I think you may want to look at `gitattributes`.

In `.gitattributes` you can define a path associated with a filter, then in `.git/config` you can configure the clean and smudge commands:

This way you can specify special behavior for a set of files.

I use this to have a centralized .gitconfig in my dotfiles, and change the email and some parameters using clean / smudge depending on the computer I am.

I think you can trick git into not modifiyng whole files the same way.

Comment: clarify: I want git to completely ignore in the sense of not updating and not seeing as added or changed, as if they were never there.  Let me alter them for my local needs, and not complain or make me redo things.

Comment: That's what gitignore is for, so I don't really understand why you don't want to use it ?

Comment: Now that you ask, I don't remember why it didn't work right. That was the first thing I had tried.